# common language for any RDBMS technology

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rdbms

We are looking for a common language for any RDBMS technology. I mean if I write a query in SQL Server that query will also have to work on any RDBMS like oracle, mysql etc.

Can anyone help get me started?

Comment: You might want a database abstraction layer of some kind, which is usually tied to some specific programming language or operating system environment.  Can you explain some more about your use case and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes I am looking for database abstraction layer for c# programming language.through the programming  suppose if I write  a query like select * from sys.databases ,this query will work in sqlserver but it wont work in oracle. i need a common API for executing  those quires in other RDBMS technologies.

Comment: The real variability isn't so much in your sql statements (your basic CRUD operations), but the extending functions of your rdbms. concat() in MySQL, for example, isn't very portable.

Comment: As @Gian suggested, the best option might be to use an ORM that already supports the RDBMS platforms you need, rather than trying to develop one yourself or limit yourself to "lowest common denominator" SQL. Have you already researched ORMs for your programming language?

Comment: +1 for ORM suggestion. An example, with ORM like NHibernate with Linq, doing paging via Skip and Take is well-abstracted. Just change the connection to Postgresql or Mysql, Skip and Take will be translated to OFFSET and LIMIT, change it to Sql Server 2005 it will use ROW_NUMBER and WHERE, change it to Sql Server 2000 it will use TOP and whatnot. Hard to abstract those paging differences across different RDBMS using common denominator SQL only

Answer (score 7):

There is an ANSI standard for SQL that's (mostly) supported by most database servers.  As long as you stick to that subset of the SQL language functionality offered by your database server your queries will be portable.

However, many of the more sophisticated features of your dbms won't be usable as they are not part of the ANSI standard, and thus implemented in a proprietary way by each dbms vendor - crosstabs are an example of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, You could use ANSI standard but not all the RDBMS support all the ANSI standard. Also, ANSI standard are only for SQL and not fo,r say their programming language like Tsql for sql server and pl/sql for oracle etc.

2nd and most important point why would you want to use the same code in different RDBMS. Database systems are totally differnet.Some RDBMS are good in doing some things and not good in other things. Thus if you implement one code then it might not be the best optimized code for some of RDBMS's. Thus I would suggest that write the code based on the strengths and weakness of a RDBMS.If it is going to be different then so be it.

Most important thing, are you trying to do some benchmark before deciding the RDBMS. Also, what purpose it will solve to have same data and code on different RDMBS. You will be wasting lots of moeny on license. server etc as code will do the same work on all the RDBMS.